# Unable to deploy heroku, git push heroku fails, NameError: undefined local variable or method `honey'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an app to heroku and have done so successfully like 10 times already for the same app, with `git push heroku`, but this is the first time it fails.  The only thing I have changed is using SendGrid for mail, and also adding my debit card to Heroku in order to use SendGrid.

I do `git push heroku` and notice the following, and 'honey' here is part of the name of my app:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: undefined local variable or method `honey' for #<SampleApp::Application:0x000055643cb61b60>
remote:        /tmp/build_2ef405515f92d4416c39b15ac05f8e6d/config/environments/production.rb:69:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_2ef405515f92d4416c39b15ac05f8e6d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
```

later in the output it says,

```
remote:        /tmp/build_2ef405515f92d4416c39b15ac05f8e6d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_2ef405515f92d4416c39b15ac05f8e6d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_2ef405515f92d4416c39b15ac05f8e6d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to honey-pot-12345.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git'
```

the only place where the word `'honey'` is at in my app code is in `production.rb`, where I assign the host and then use it for mail:

```
host = 'https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
```

I tried searching but not sure any answers I have seen specify this issue, any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you have in `config/environments/production.rb:69`?

Comment: `host = 'https://honey-pot-12345.herokuapp.com'` is on `config/environments/production.rb:69`

Comment: It is because there is nothing there. Check the host.

Comment: @MatiasCarpintini. thank you, nothing there?  As in nothing in the `production.rb` file?  I can visit the site, I Just changed my app name to something generic since this is a public forum(not sure if there would be any privacy concerns or not), that isn't a real link to a heroku app, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Cant seem to find any issue with your configuration but might want to try this as well if still problem persist try using " instead of '

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git' }
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian!  Ah, you mean use double quotes instead of single quotes, I may try that. I actually reverted just a few changes related to trying to use SendGrid in production and was able to do `git push heroku` successfully, so I know it has to do with what I'm doing at this last step of this phase of a project.  Will let you know if it does infact work, but I do have a working github solution from someone else that uses single quotes, so don't expect that to be the issue, but never know.

Comment: I realize also that using the variable host will result into this { 'https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git' : 'https://git.heroku.com/honey-pot-12345.git' }

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:  Actually just reverted code to a previous working version and then pushed succesfully from heroku form there, then built out my feature again by copying - instead of typing - code I needed, and it worked. Thanks for help everyone!